# Bathroom AC outlets out

Tags: receptacle, power

All outlets (non-gfci) in both of my bathrooms (at sink level) are dead. I have cycled all service breakers to no avail. Have had no known recent electrical 'disturbance'

Comment: Are both bathrooms fed with the same breaker? If they are they were probably wired using the push in connections called stabs, these can be problematic.

Comment: With power off check the last outlet that has power for a loose or burned off white or black wire, then check the first dead outlet, this will be the location to check. If a damaged stab , loose or burned off replace the outlet or if it has side screws use these to secure the wire white wire on silver screw black wire on brass screw

Comment: CB box note claims only one breaker. '92 construction....all using side screw termination. Nothing loose, burnt, etc. Maybe issue AT the breaker?

Comment: Look for a tripped GFCI in a strange place -- garage, outdoors, basement... I regularly see multiple bathrooms fed from a single gfci that's nowhere near the rooms.

Comment: Thanks AD! Your intelligience knows no bounds!....found mentioned tripped gfci in the garage indeed!

Comment: @Dave -- you're welcome. But I think "hard won experience" might trump intelligence in this case.

Answer (score 2):

As comments disappear over time, and this might be searched in the future, I'll just copy/paste the relevant comments that led to resolution...

> (me) Look for a tripped GFCI in a strange place -- garage, outdoors,
>   basement... I regularly see multiple bathrooms fed from a single gfci
>   that's nowhere near the rooms. – Aloysius Defenestrate 16 hours ago
>
> (OP) Thanks AD! Your intelligience knows no bounds!....found mentioned
>   tripped gfci in the garage indeed! – Dave 14 hours ago

Comment: Funny, it's usually the other way around, with the GFCI outlet in a bathroom and the garage as its load.